# Find the sum of a pair of columns starting from first and the middle one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, sum

My input:

```
a b c d e f
g h i j k l
```

My output should have three sets of solutions like this:

```
Sq( a**2 + d**2 ) + Sq ( g**2 + j**2 )
Sq( b**2 + e**2 ) + Sq ( h**2 + k**2 )
Sq( c**2 + f**2 ) + Sq ( i**2 + l**2 )
```

My actual text file has so many rows and columns with no header. This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np


for file in os.listdir("directory"):  
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        fin=open(file, 'r')
        total = 0
        for line in fin:
            str = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
            for i in range(len(str[0:5])):
                str[i]=float(str[i])                   
                sum=np.sum((math.pow(str[i],2)+math.pow(str[i+3],2))**0.5
                total += sum
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

With a file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Correcting indention and range:

```
with open('stack53269737.txt') as f:
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        str = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
        for i in range(3):
            str[i]=float(str[i])                   
            sum=np.sum((math.pow(str[i],2)+math.pow(str[i+3],2))**0.5)
            total += sum

In [111]: total
Out[111]: 73.84586902040324
```

with further cleanup

```
with open('stack53269737.txt') as f:
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        alist = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
        for i in range(3):                   
            total += (alist[i]**2+alist[i+3]**2)**0.5
```

We don't need to convert to `float` twice; we don't need `math` for simple squares.

A numpy approach:

load it with a numpy csv reader:

```
In [126]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack53269737.txt')
In [127]: data
Out[127]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16.]])
```

reshape the array to express your row splitting:

```
In [128]: data1 = data.reshape(2,2,3)
In [129]: data1
Out[129]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.]],

       [[11., 12., 13.],
        [14., 15., 16.]]])
```

Now we can just square all values, sum on the correct axis, take squareroot and sum again:

```
In [130]: np.sum(np.sum(data1**2, axis=1)**.5)
Out[130]: 73.84586902040324
```

Comment: Beautiful solution in numpy with reshape.

Comment: How can I have the solutions separately instead of the total? since 73.8458 = 21.9276498 + 24.5945375 + 27.3237320

Comment: just omit the relevant `sum`

Comment: Your original code calculates one `total`; I'm just following its example.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it without `numpy`, you could try the following:

```
import math

with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:
    # Split the lines and then split numbers from each line.
    lines = list(map(str.split, infile.read().split('\n')))
    # Use zip to create tuples of values that take part in each operation.
    lines = list(zip(*lines))
    # Get length of each line.
    lineLength = len(lines)
    # Find the total.
    total = sum([math.sqrt(int(lines[i][j])**2 + int(lines[i+3][j])**2) for i in range(lineLength-3) for j in range(2)])
    print(total)
```

Given a file with the following data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

The result is:

```
57.02450048972068
```